# how to develop java application without taking any user defined class?

Tags: java

is it possible to create any application that can use only built-in classes?
application like addition or another basic operations

ex built in classes like 
class String{}
class Object{}

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Why?

Comment: If you don't count the application class itself, why not.

Comment: Actually all you need for ANY calculations is `|` or `&`.

Comment: If the user of the application is a different person than the developer, then it is no problem.

Comment: i am new in java teacher ask me this question so i want some practical proof to know that it is possible how?

Comment: ardshaji's answer below gives you an example. You can extend that by declaring variable of types such as int and doing compuations with them, for example int x =7; int y = 9; x +=y;

Comment: @djna I really think this question tends more to being able to prove that anything can be done with standard java libraries.

Comment: Cruncher, so it's "prove Java is a Turing machine" ? Practically, some Java libraries incorporate native code, so it's clear that it's considered impractical to do it all in Java ...

Comment: @djna That's what it's sounding like. That was the point of my earlier comment about `|` and `&`. Actually, you don't even need both, since you can demorgan's.

Comment: @djna I think you need `not` as well.

Comment: Nooo, the question got put on hold. I just wrote code adding 2 2-bit numbers with | & and ~.

Comment: `byte total = (byte) ((((2 & num1) & ~(2 & num2) | ~(2 & num1) & (2 & num2)) & ~(~((1 & num1) & ~(1 & num2) | ~(1 & num1) & (1 & num2)) & ((1 & num1) | (1 & num2))) | (~((1 & num1) & ~(1 & num2) | ~(1 & num1) & (1 & num2)) & ((1 & num1) | (1 & num2))) & ~((2 & num1) & ~(2 & num2) | ~(2 & num1) & (2 & num2))) | ((1 & num1) & ~(1 & num2) | ~(1 & num1) & (1 & num2)));` if anyone is interested lol. (it did have variables, I jumbled it into 1 expression)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean fully. If you mean an application that doesn't instantiate any non-standard classes, then yes of course, here:

```
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

If you mean an application in which we don't *have* any non-standard classes at all, then no: you need to have a `main()` method in some class somewhere.

Comment: no dear using only built in classes and variables(fields)/methods

Comment: You have no choice you must declare a class for your main. After that the example is exactly doing what you ask. It uses built in classes String and System, part of the standard JRE.

Comment: yes by using only predefined classes any program pls tell me

Comment: @jayeshbsk5 In what way does the snippet in my answer not do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, yeah. All existing libraries either use built-in methods or use another library that does, or somewhere down the chain built in methods will be used.

All you would be doing is recreating functionality someone already built.

Comment: yes i want that. but how i dont know pls tell me

Answer (score 0):

"Any" application no.."an" application yes

Comment: Outside of libraries that interact with the OS, like GUIs, then it's actually all possible.

Comment: which pls tell me practically

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write the class that contains your main(), so strictly speaking, no. But apart from that, you can get quite a lot done with the standard JRE library.

Comment: but how i dont know pls tell me

Comment: not fully functional application only basic operation need to use in application without declaring user defined class (class should be predefined in java)

Answer (score 0):

JAVA is an object oriented language so in normal usage you would define classes. However, you can do pure functional programming in JAVA, without instantiating any user defined object. But every function must be contained in a class, so you will need to define at least a single class that holds your application logic.

```
 class MyOnlyClassThatIDontInstantiate{
      public static void main(String args[]){
           System.out.println("Hello world!");
           System.out.println("2 + 3 = "+addNumbers(2,3));
      }
      public static int addNumbers(int a, int b){
          return a+b;
      }
 }
```

The above is a futile application that only uses functional programming. No classes are instantiated, but the main method has to be enclosed in a class.

Comment: MyOnlyClassThatIDontInstatiate........... this is built in class? reply

Comment: @jayeshbsk5 No, as I explained above, you have to define at least one class, because all code needs to be contained in a class. Java does not know the concept of code outside a class. If you want to write code, it has to be contained in a class. I named the class `MyOnlyClassThatIDontInstantiate`. All functions are declared `static` so they can run without instantiating the class. That means, I don't have to call `new MyOnlyClassThatIDontInstantiate()`